# applying a Function using apply() in pandas

Tags: pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find the distance of a datapoint to the regression line.
For this, as suggested in another question, i have written the function. However, when i try to apply it, i am not succesful.
The reason is that this function needs to be apply after groupby
The function is as below

```
    def regress(yvar, xvar):
       X = xvar.values[:,np.newaxis]
       Y = yvar.values
       model=LinearRegression()
       model.fit(X,Y)
       dist = Y - model.predict(X)
    return dist
```

And i am trying to apply it after groupby as below
name of my dataframe is "data_train_bel1800" and "Time" and "Values" are columns that contain the values that need to be fed into the function

```
    data_train_bel1800['distance'] = (data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle','Type']).apply(regress(data_train_bel1800['Time'].values,data_train_bel1800['Values'].values)))
```

I think I am doing error when passing he values of the columns Time & Values. Can anyone guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def regress(yvar, xvar):
    X = xvar.values[:,np.newaxis]
    Y = yvar
    model=LinearRegression()
    res = model.fit(X,Y)
    dist = Y - res.predict(X)
    return dist

test = pd.read_csv('Training.csv')
test.drop(['EndTime'],axis=1,inplace=True)

res= test.groupby(['Cycle','Type'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: regress(x["Time"], x['Values']))
test["distance"] = res.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

print(test)
```

```
 Cycle Type Time    Values  distance
0   2   2   101.0   20.402  426.813637
1   2   2   102.0   20.402  427.813637
2   2   2   103.0   20.402  428.813637
3   2   2   104.0   20.402  429.813637
```

Comment: i get the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'"

Comment: I think the error is due to this X = xvar.values[:,np.newaxis] Y = yvar.values

Comment: try to provide data in your question on which you are apply this function

Comment: kindly add data in question so that I can check

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong too. The csv file with the data is in the link [sharecsv.com/s/1f3b09e6234cac5842f1f35fb9f87752/Training.csv] you can ignore the 'EndTime' column

Comment: unfortunately, not working for me the distance column shows "32.902618
33.902618
34.902618
35.902618" as distance values whereas the distance should be something like 0.012....something.

Comment: you need to look on the logic of regress if the distance answer is incorrect then the issue is with the logic

Comment: I just checked the issue that you mentioned in question that unable to pass column

Comment: you are correct. it was the issue with the logic. yvar was assigned to X & xvar was assigned to Y. I correct it & it is working now. Thanks a lot.